# ng-repeat on two (or more) rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

My `array`:

```
$scope.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

My `HTML`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">{{item}}</span>
```

This will output, as expected: `12345678910`.

But I want to display the `array` over two `rows`, as in the following sample:

```
12345 // break here
678910
```

I run some functions on this array, so I don't want to split the array into two smaller ones, cause that would mean I have to run these other functions twice as often. I have looked into the 'start end' part of [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), but honestly, I don't understand how it works, thoughts?

**Note**: this is an ionic application, if that matters.

**Edit**: I can't get the suggested answers to work, I though I could dumb down my code, and make it work, but no. this is my full html `ng-repeat` code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col" ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
      {{item}}
      <br ng-if="$index == 4">
   </div>
</div>
```

This did not work, how come? Anything with `row` or `col`?

Comment: What isn't working - ie what is the output? Is it still just `1234567810` all in one line?

Comment: yes, exactly, all in one line

Comment: It will be to do with the styling and the fact that you are using a `div`, could you try `<div class="col">
            <span ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">{{item}}
            <br ng-if="$index == 4"></span>
        </div>` - basically move the `ng-repeat` to a `span` inside your `div`, which wraps both `{{item}}` and `<br>`

Comment: thank you, that did the trick, so it was the `div` element, I guess, thanks (update your answer and I'll accept)

Comment: great, I've updated my answer to reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-if` to insert a new line when the `$index` is equal to `4`:

```
<div class="col"> 
    <span ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
        {{item}}
        <br ng-if="$index==4">
    </span>
</div>
```

Here, we also move the `ng-repeat` to a `span` element inside the `div`. This solves any potential issues which may arise from the styling applied to the `div`.

Comment: your second method won't work. Each one will get it's own `p` since 1 <= 4, 2 <= 4, ...

Comment: hmm, I can't get it to work.. maybe it has something to do with ionic? I will post my full `ng-repeat` html code in an edit, I must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

You could also experiment with item.$middle.

> item.$middle: true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
    {{item}} <br ng-if="item.$middle" />
</div>
```

?

Comment: just in time, I was about to repeat the comment i gave @gtlambert ;)